# Pycharm and Pyspark link

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to get Pyspark to run in my Pycharm IDE (MacOS). It had been running ok in terminal, but now wont. I have read the other Pycharm threads, so I have added in the ContentRoot and defined SPARKHOME in the interpreter, but I still receive this error and I am struggling to decypher the issue:

```
22/03/15 20:14:43 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Toms-MacBook-Air-3.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.94.0.1; using 192.168.0.6 instead (on interface en0)
22/03/15 20:14:43 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/03/15 20:14:44 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-1fb8b80eea10>", line 3, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/SparkCourse/total-spend-per-customer.py', wdir='/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/SparkCourse')
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/SparkCourse/total-spend-per-customer.py", line 5, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 209, in _do_init
    self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
    return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1585, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Frustratingly, it has also adversely impacted it running on my terminal aswell, the error I get there is:

```
22/03/15 20:15:44 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Toms-MacBook-Air-3.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.XXX.X.X instead (on interface en0)
22/03/15 20:15:44 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.2.1
22/03/15 20:15:45 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO ResourceUtils: No custom resources configured for spark.driver.
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: TotalCustomerSpend
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO ResourceProfile: Default ResourceProfile created, executor resources: Map(cores -> name: cores, amount: 1, script: , vendor: , memory -> name: memory, amount: 1024, script: , vendor: , offHeap -> name: offHeap, amount: 0, script: , vendor: ), task resources: Map(cpus -> name: cpus, amount: 1.0)
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO ResourceProfile: Limiting resource is cpu
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO ResourceProfileManager: Added ResourceProfile id: 0
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: Tom
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: Tom
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
22/03/15 20:15:45 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(Tom); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(Tom); groups with modify permissions: Set()
22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 59597.
22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tom/PycharmProjects/SparkCourse/total-spend-per-customer.py", line 5, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 146, in __init__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 209, in _do_init
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 329, in _initialize_context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1585, in __call__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x3c60b7e7
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/03/15 20:15:46 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/k1/g12y2m210zlb4bsh_f3w6tm40000gn/T/spark-cdf0bd15-d0cf-446c-8136-1e9ee768ce9e
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to eventually solve this. I needed to add JAVA_HOME path to both my terminal and my Pycharm Environment Variables. Once that was done, it seems to run ok!

Comment: add in your .bash_profile config